# How to send both php and javascript variables as input field value?

Tags: javascript, php

I am sending multiple values from the input field with the same name.
It works fine when I just send the custom1 and var 2 but I want to add a javascript variable var3 as well but assigning the value by using document.getElemendById overwrites the input field completely and custom1 and var2 are lost. So how to add a javascript variable var3 at the end so it gets printed under the array index $pieces[2]; in the v.php file.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php $var2 = "custom2" ?>
    <form action="v.php" method="POST" >
    <input id="jsvar" type="text" name="custom" value="custom1,<?php echo $var2; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="send">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var var3 = "custom3";
            document.getElementById("jsvar").value = var3;
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

v.php

```
    <?php  
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];
    $pattern = ",";
    $pieces = explode($pattern,$custom, 3);
    print_r($pieces);
    $custom1 = $pieces[0];
    $custom2 = $pieces[1];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $custom1.'<br>';
    echo $custom2.'<br>';
    echo $pieces[2];
    ?>
```

Comment: Where is `jsvar` in your form?

Comment: its there in the first file

Answer (score 3):

You could append the data rather than replace it with the new data.

```
var var3 = "custom3";
document.getElementById("jsvar").value += ","+var3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this below . It's working fine. Review below screen [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku0G7.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php $var2 = "custom2" ?>
    <form action="v.php" method="POST" >
    <input id="jsvar" type="text" name="custom" value="custom1,<?php echo $var2; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="send">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var pre_value=document.getElementById("jsvar").value;
            var var3 = "custom3";
            var new_value = pre_value +','+var3;
            document.getElementById("jsvar").value = new_value;
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yea thanks, it works and appending with += also does the same. document.getElementById("jsvar").value += ","+var3;